# Implement HPKP in ASP.Net application

Tags: asp.net

I have learned about the HPKP recently and I wanted to know how to correctly implement this in an MVC application.

Comment: I'm seeing a lot of hits when I Google your title. Have you done some research already?

Comment: This is the top hit on Google for HPKP asp.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are thinking about a code level implementation, you can do the following in the startup class using IAppBuilder

```
app.UseHpkp(options => options
    .Sha256Pins(
        "Base Certificate Hash value and Backup certificate hash value")
    .MaxAge(days: <Expiration Time>));
```

You can generate the required hash values using the openssl tool using your certificate file.

If you do not about the exact implementation, it is best to use the [OWASP ASP.NET MVC Boilerplate Project](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_ASP.NET_MVC_Boilerplate_Project). All the security implementations are pre-build in to this template and you can carry-on build your application on top of it.